# WebApi - How to include relative paths for included App_Data XML files?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api

**Question Background:**

I have a WebApi controller who's logic code relies on reading data contained in a number of XML files. These XML files have been included in the `App_Data` folder of the WebApi project.

**The Issue:**

I'm trying to use the relative path of the XML files in the following way:

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public string CallerOne()
    {
        string docOne = @"~\AppData\DocOne.xml";

        string poll = @"~\AppData\Poll.xml";

        var response =  _Caller.CallService(docOne, poll);

        return ConvertXmlToJson(response);
    }
```

When running the WebApi code and calling the Url to the `CallerOne` method I receive the following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException'
occurred in  System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not find a part of the path
'C:\Program Files  (x86)\IIS Express\~\AppData\FPS.xml'.
```

I also want to eventually publish this to Azure and include these files.

**How can I use the relative path to read in the XML files in the `App_Data`** folder?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Ended up finding the answer.

The following is needed to read the relative paths in a WebApi project:

```
var fullPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/yourXmlFile.xml");
```

Comment: How about this :  string appData = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppData");

Comment: @jdweng - But it's not an environment variable, the OP is trying to get to the App_Data folder in his webapi deployment.  The answer provided above worked fine, your way produced a path of C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming, which isn't what is needed.

Comment: How do you know what the OP wanted two years ago?

Comment: @jdweng, OP clearly stated it in question: "These XML files have been included in the `App_Data` folder of the WebApi project." Usage of `AppData` later in non-working code example should not be considered, and by the way, is simply a typo.

Answer (score 7):

As jdweng inferred several months back, ***Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppData")*** would seem to be the preferred method. The OP's auto-accepted answer and that give quite different results. For example, using both of those in my project, I get:

```
C:\\Projects\\PlatypusReports\\PlatypusReports\\App_Data\\yourXmlFile.xml
```

...for the OP's long-winded code, namely this:

```
var fullPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/yourXmlFile.xml");
```

...and this:

```
C:\\Users\\cshannon\\AppData\\Roaming
```

...for jdweng's code, to wit:

```
string appData = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppData");
```

OTOH, this code:

```
string appDataFolder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/");
```

returns:

```
C:\\Projects\\PlatypusReports\\PlatypusReports\App_Data\
```

So it's very similar in results (if not methodology) to the first example above. I actually got it from [a question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639441/can-i-write-a-file-to-a-folder-on-a-server-machine-from-a-web-api-app-running-on) almost two years ago, which I had forgotten about.

I'm not positive if jdweng's approach would work as expected once the app is deployed on a server, but I have much more confidence in it than the other approaches.

Can anyone verify?

### UPDATE

The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268738/asp-net-mvc-find-absolute-path-to-the-app-data-folder-from-controller) has 237 upvotes at time of typing, so seems pretty reliable, albeit 6 years old (42 in dog years, which may be a good sign).

Comment: The accepted answer in you update is using HttpContext which you generally wouldn't access in WebApi

Comment: @heymega: Would that mean the best method is to use OP's original answer: `HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data");`?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine. You just had some tpying error,
You wrote

```
string docOne = @"~\AppData\DocOne.xml";
```

But it should have been

```
string docOne = @"~\App_Data\DocOne.xml";
```